# WxPython BitmapButton not clickable

Tags: python, events, wxpython, wxwidgets

So, I am trying to make this program for a project I was assigned. The code is still a draft and I really didn't know anything about wxPython when I was assigned this project.

Anyway. What this program does, is create an application that manages photo albums. I got it to create/remove folders and be able to change its root directory and move the program files elsewhere. I also got it to generate bitmap buttons for each 'album' and place them in a FlexGridSizer.

My problem is that these Bitmap Buttons are unclickable.

```
class RightPanel(wx.Panel):
    global path
    def __init__(self, parent):
        a = wx.GetDisplaySize()
        width = 3 * a[0] / 4
        height = 3 * a[1] / 4
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent=parent,
                          size=(3*width/4, height),
                          style=wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetBackgroundColour('dark grey')
        self.widgetSizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)





class MasterPanel(wx.Panel):
    global delete, CurrentDirg, locale
    delete = False
    a = wx.GetDisplaySize()
    width = 3 * a[0] / 4
    height = 3 * a[1] / 4
    id = {}

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.MasterPanel = wx.Panel(self,
                                    wx.ID_ANY,
                                    size=(self.width, self.height),
                                    )
        self.SetBackgroundColour('light grey')
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        splitter1 = wx.SplitterWindow(self)
        splitter2 = wx.SplitterWindow(splitter1)

        left_pt = LeftPanelTop(splitter2)
        left_pb = LeftPanelBottom(splitter2)
        self.rightP = RightPanel(splitter1)
        self.boxsizer2 = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        splitter2.SetSashGravity(0.5)
        splitter2.SplitHorizontally(left_pt, left_pb)

        splitter1.SplitVertically(splitter2, self.rightP)
        splitter1.SetSashGravity(0.5)

        self.gSizer = wx.FlexGridSizer(0, 5, 10, 10)

        self.dir_search()
        self.boxsizer2.Add(self.gSizer, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL)
        self.rightP.SetSizer(self.boxsizer2)
        self.boxsizer2.Layout()
        self.sizer.Add(splitter1, 1, wx.EXPAND)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)

    def dir_search(self):
        global path, delete

        try:
            if self.id != {} or delete == True:
                sizer = self.gSizer
                for i in sizer.GetChildren():
                    sizer.Hide(0)
                    sizer.Remove(0)

                    self.boxsizer2.Layout()
            self.gSizer.Layout()
            self.id = {}
            with open('albums.dir', mode='r', buffering=1) as alb:
                names = alb.readlines()
                for i in range(len(names)):
                    names[i] = names[i].rstrip('\n')
                paths = [path + '\\' + i for i in names]
            counter = 0

            for i in paths:
                self.dirimcreate(i, counter)
                counter += 1
            print(self.id)
        except Exception as E:
            print(E)
            sizer = self.gSizer
            while sizer.GetChildren():
                sizer.Hide(0)
                sizer.Remove(0)
        self.boxsizer2.Layout()

    def dirimcreate(self, path, counter):
        pic = wx.Image('input.ico', wx.BITMAP_TYPE_ANY)
        pic = pic.Scale(self.width / 10, self.width / 10, wx.IMAGE_QUALITY_HIGH)
        pic = pic.ConvertToBitmap()

        self.saasda = wx.BitmapButton(self.rightP,
                                      wx.ID_ANY,
                                      pic,
                                      size=(self.width / 10, self.width / 10),
                                      style=wx.NO_BORDER
                                      )
        self.saasda.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.chdir)
        self.saasda.SetDefault()
        self.saasda.myname = self.saasda.GetId()

        self.id[self.saasda.GetId()] = path
        self.gSizer.Add(self.saasda, 0, wx.ALL, 5)

        self.boxsizer2.Layout()

    def chdir(self, event):
        self.Info(message='You clicked a button')
```

This is what the result looks like.
[image: The program]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: you didn't create any handler for the click and bind the handler to the button. Also it would be nice to cut you code posting to be as minimal as possible - just put the code for a panel with buttons.

Comment: Isn't this what 'self.saasda.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.chdir)' does?

Comment: this is for self.saasda button. Where are the binding for all other?

Comment: There is too much code here, please reduce it to something (much) simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

It seems that the code for the MasterPanel class included a size parameter in the init, which created an invisible panel that covered everything else, rendering it unclickable.